# How to fake your location to test website translation

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, microsoft-edge

I've added the simple Google translation to a website that I've developed and *apparantly* it defaults to the target language translation if the browser detects a user from that country.

I'm based in the UK and the site shows (obviously) English with an option to translate into French.

Is there any way I can 'fake' my location to fool the website into thinking I'm browsing from France ?

Answer (score -1):

**It depends on how a website has been designed and programmed**. Usually a website would store visiter language preferences in the site cookie and remember your language preferences the next time you visit the web site. You can change how IE tells websites what language(s) to display content in (if its available from the website) from Tools>Internet Options>General tab, Language button.